# cURL error 28: Connection timed out

Tags: civicrm-event, errorhandling

Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Siteground.
All of a sudden starting today, when users attempt to register for events, they get the registration form, fill it out, and when they click the button to do the final register, it pops the following message:  cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1001 milliseconds (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Where is this controlled and how do we either fix it or lengthen the connection timeout parameter?

Comment: In addition to the above error, other folks are getting this error:  No PSR-18 clients found. Make sure to install a package providing "psr/http-client-implementation". Example: "php-http/guzzle7-adapter".  I assume both error messages are related but cannot find any documentation to derive an answer from.

Comment: In my case, disabling Geocoder stopped the error reporting. Not a great solution but it suggest that a recent change in Geocoder is part of the problem.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Apparently reverting to v. 1.10 works. See https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.geocoder/issues/60

Comment: Yes, we disabled geocoder and all is well.